# Huge memory consumption on list .split()

Tags: python

I have a simple function that read a file and returns a list of words:

```
def _read_words(filename):
  with tf.gfile.GFile(filename, "r") as f:
      words = f.read().replace("\n"," %s " % EOS).split()

  print(" %d Mo" % (sys.getsizeof(words)/(1000*1000)))
  return words
```

**Notes:**

- the `tf.gfile.GFile` comes from TensorFlow, the same is happening with `open` so you can ignore it.
- `EOS` is a string containing "`<eos>`"

---

When I run it with a 1.3GB file, the process reserve more than **20GB of RAM** (see `htop` screenshot), but it prints `2353 Mo` for `sys.getsizeof(words)`.

[image]

Note that this process is nothing more than:

```
import reader
path = "./train.txt"
w = reader._read_words(path)
```

When I run it step by step I see the following:

- `d = file.read()` => 4.039 GB RAM
- `d = d.replace('\n', ' <eos> ')` => 5.4GB RAM
- `d = d.split()` => 22GB RAM

---

So here I am:

- I can understand that split uses extra memory, but that much looks ridiculous.
- Could I use better operations/data structures to do it? A solution using `numpy` would be great.
- **I can find a workaround (see below) specific to my case, but I would still not understand why I can't do it the easiest way.**

Any clues or suggestion are welcome,
Thx,
Paul

---

**Workaround:**
As explained in the comment I need to:

1. Build a vocabulary i.e. a dict `{"word": count}`.
2. Then I select only the top `n` word, by occurence (n being a parameter)
3. Each of these words are assigned a integer (1 to n, 0 is for end of sentence tag `<eos>`)
4. I load the whole data, spliting by sentence (`\n` or our internal tag `<eos>`)
5. We sort it by sentence length

What I can do better:

1. Count words on the fly (line by line)
2. Build the vocabulary using this word count (we don't need the whole data then)
3. Load the whole data as integers, using the vocabulary, and therefore saving some memory.
4. Sort the list, same length, less memory consumption.

Comment: why don't you iterate over the file handle *lazily*, like `for line in f:` rather than reading the whole thing into memory with `f.read()`?

Comment: That does sound high. It is making a list with a newly allocated string for every word. I would expect it to at least double, plus some overhead (per word).

Comment: @Chris_Rands : thx for suggestion, in fact I do need the whole data as I am sorting the data after that.

Comment: Without stretching my brain enough to justify giving an actual answer, I wonder if the reserved memory isn't there as a cap to the list? Underneath the list is a backing array in C, which has to take some space. For efficiency, this array is larger than the list (so not every call to `list.append` builds a new, longer backing array and copies into it). How certain are you that you need to get this data back in the manner you describe? Despite your insistence that you need the information sorted, I wonder if there's not a better data structure for you.

Comment: @AdamSmith : the first thing I do from these data is building a vocabulary i.e. a dict mapping each word to its #occurences, and assign it an id. It could be done without loading the whole data for sure. Then I map each word to its id. So I am actually sorting integer list wrt its length, so I do need the whole data at one step, but it can be integers, which would save some memory. 
The thing is, it quite disapointing that I need 20G RAM or go into more complex solution to retrieve a list of words from a small file, isn't it?

Comment: @pltrdy you could look into a `collections.Counter` for the occurrences bit. It will definitely be cheaper to have a list of ints compared to a list of strings (since strings are just lists of chars)

Comment: @AdamSmith : Thx for the advice, I'm actually using it. In fact, my code first use `_read_words` then use `Counter` on it. I could count line by line, build vocabulary, and only then, load the whole data as integers

Comment: @pltrdy I don't think you're going to avoid using a large amount of memory if you call `f.read` on a large file. Avoid that if it's prudent to avoid a large memory sink. Remember that `Counter`s implement `__iadd__` so you can iterate by-line and use an accumulator pattern.

Comment: @AdamSmith the f.read in itself "only" uses 4GB. Which is quite ok. The split is the source of the problem.
Thx for the `Counter` trick, nice to know ;)